# Webpage resets and stops applying CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am producing a webpage for class featuring a build your own story using JavaScript. At the beginning, the user inputs their name and picks their gender (clicks on image representing gender), then I use removeChild to make the gender images disappear and start the story with a fresh page excluding the title. But once the user selects a gender, the CSS I've applied seems to be ignored by the webpage - black background turns white, text centering is ignored. Why is this, and how can I have CSS consistent through the webpage while still doing what I want to do?

HTML:

```
var name = prompt("Welcome! To begin, please tell me your name:");
    var gender = 0;
    var maleImage = 0;
    var femaleImage = 0;
    var genderPrompt = 0;

    document.writeln("<h2>Hello " + name + "! Welcome to Design Your Own Story! " + 
                     "In this game, you pick how the story goes!</h2><h2 id='genderPrompt'>Let's begin. Click which gender you are.</h2>");

    document.writeln("<img id='maleImage' src='maleImage.jpg' alt='Male Image' onclick='genderChoice(1)' />");
    document.writeln("<img id='femaleImage' src='femaleImage.jpg' alt='Female Image' onclick='genderChoice(2)' />");

    function genderChoice(genderImage) {
        if (genderImage === 1) {
            gender = "male";
        } else {
            gender = "female";
        }
        setTimeout(genderReset,250);

    }

    function genderReset() {
        if (gender === "female") {  
            maleImage = document.getElementById("maleImage");
            maleImage.parentNode.removeChild(maleImage);
        }
        if (gender === "male") {
            femaleImage = document.getElementById("femaleImage");
            femaleImage.parentNode.removeChild(femaleImage);
        }
        genderPrompt = document.getElementById("genderPrompt");
        genderPrompt.parentNode.removeChild(genderPrompt);

        document.writeln("<h1 class='title'>Design Your Own Story</h1>");
        document.writeln("<h2>Ok, " + name + ", so you're " + gender + "! Let's start our journey...</h2>");
        setTimeout(leavesHome,1500);
    }
```

CSS:

```
* {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

img {
    width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript does not recognize the `genderCoice` function. You are probably running the code in a closure.

Try assigning it to an object (I took `document` for the example, though it's not necessarily best practice):

```
document.genderChoice = function(genderImage) {
    if (genderImage === 1) {
        gender = "male";
    } else {
        gender = "female";
    }
    setTimeout(genderReset,250);

}
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/bb5hsrrp/embedded/result/) working.
(the fiddle itself broke, probably because of the `writeln`, can't edit it further)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use `document.writeln` after the document has finished loading.  You should only use `document.writeln` on an open document, once the document becomes closed `document.writeln` will cause the contents to be erased.  This is what is erasing your style sheet.

To modify the page after it has loaded, you should do something like this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<span>Some new text here</span>";
```

Or precreate your elements in your index page and then use them to set the innerHtml:

```
<body>
   <div id="section"></div>
</body>
```

Then in your code:

```
var section = document.getElementById("section");
section.innerHTML = "<span>Some new text goes here</span>";
```

Comment: How can I use innerHTML to add text using the further functions I already have in place? At the moment I just keep using document.writeln to add text to the page